# Hasse Diagram in DAKS package of R

Tags: r, diagram

I am really confused that how making a Hasse diagram of the following data?

```
node  L    R
  31  4 <  5
  33 31 >  7
  34  6 > 33
  32  1 < 34
  23  2 <  3
  30 23 > 32
  29  8 < 30
  27  9 > 10
  28 27 > 29
  26 28 < 12 
  25 26 < 17
  24 11 > 25
  19 14 > 15 
  20 19 > 16
  21 13 > 20
  22 21 < 24
```

Comment: You might start by entering code that would show that you know how to make a dataframe. And then make a set-object as specified in the help page for `DAKS::Hasse`. Your code should load any needed packages, too.

Comment: Could you help me that how to code it?

Comment: Show your work. We don't know where you get stuck. This is not a place to ask for people to do your homework.

Comment: First of all, It's not my homework. I am writing a research paper and want to visualize these relationships in one diagram. That I found a Hasse diagram can do this and it is available in R. I have seen a simple example of the Hasse diagram of numbers are divisable. But I am here confused how to code this in the case of less than or greater than.

Comment: I was using the term "homework" in the generic sense of stuff you should have already done on your own. If you don't know how to create dataframes, read help pages, and  load dependencies for packages, then SO is not the right place to be posting your confusion.

Comment: This is question is related to Hasse diagram that how we build Hasse diagram for the specific problem. If you dont have any idea about Hasse diagram then its ok.